# Getting the difference of two sums from the same table

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I need to get the difference of a query result from the same table.

Ex: myTable

```
id    code     status     amount
1       A       active      250
2       A       active      200
3       B       active      300
4       B       active      100
5       A       active      100
6       C       active      120
7       C       active      200
```

I want to get the total or sum of amount for each code (add if active, subtract if inactive status) so that i will have a result like this:

```
code   total amount
A         150
B         400
C          80
```

i have tried a lot already, one of them is this:

```
SELECT code, amount1-amount2
FROM (
    SELECT code, SUM(amount) AS amount1
    FROM mytable
    WHERE status='active'
    GROUP BY code
    UNION ALL
    SELECT code, SUM(amount) AS amount2
    FROM mytable
    WHERE status='inactive'
    GROUP BY code
) as T1
GROUP BY code
```

Comment: Set up a [fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com) and play with it

Comment: Including sample data along with desired output is good, but it's even better if the desired output actually is derived from the sample data. (In this case it can't be as there are no 'inactive' rows in the set).

Comment: Your description does not match the provided example. Looks like you actually subtract some *active* amounts. Please clarify your question.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution would be to use a case expression inside the sum function:

```
SELECT 
    code, 
    sum(case when status='active' then amount else amount * -1 end) as total_amount
FROM mytable
GROUP BY code
```

If there can be other statuses besides active/inactive you have to be more explicit:

```
sum(
   case 
      when status = 'active'   then amount 
      when status = 'inactive' then amount * -1
   end
) AS total
```

Comment: @leonbloy Thanks for noticing, it didn't make it in the copy/paste :p

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH A AS
(SELECT
   code,
   CASE WHEN status='active' THEN amount ELSE -amount END AS signed_amount
FROM myTable)

SELECT code, sum(signed_amount) FROM A GROUP BY code;
```

Comment: Note that you will get the expected result in the example you give if you set the second 'A' and the first 'C' to 'inactive'. Otherwise, all get summed.